# Why use _.each it only returns the original list

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

I'm clearly doing something wrong but I can't seem to get the values I'm seeking using _.each

I have a number of key value pairs, where each value is an array of objects. I want to get a value out of each object in the array and then sum those values.  The code:

```
var step = {key: array[1], key1: array[3]}

array = [object, object . . .]
object = {objKey: value, objKey1: value}
```

I want to get:

```
var step1 = {key: value, key: value}//where value is the sum of objKey
 in each object in the array for each key in step.
```

I'm using the following to try and get that:

```
_.each(step, function(n){return _.compact(_.pluck(n,
 "amount")).reduce(function (a, b) {return a + b;}, 0);})
```

Comment: Use [`_.map()`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) instead of [`_.each()`](http://underscorejs.org/#each)

Comment: Ok, I could do that and if I do that then I only get the array instead of the key value pairs seen in var step1. Plus, what's the point _.each then?

Comment: @rashadb: `each` is only good for executing side effects, when you don't care about the return value.

Comment: Could you please use some executable (e.g. JSON) input and expected output representation (event if's lengthy)? I don't get how your data looks.

Comment: Sorry Bergi, I've never done that before and I don't know how to do that in SO. Where do I get started?

Comment: Ok, maybe you could go into a little detail by what you mean by 'side effects' how can I use the side effects?

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions. I just discovered _.mapObject in a newer version of underscore that I didn't have in my underscore 1.7. The update made the difficult simple! Thank you underscore!!!

Comment: My apologies for wasting anyone's time.  I'm learning (almost completely self-taught with Stack Overflow as my main source and teacher) and sometimes I don't even know what I'm trying to ask as I have no one to turn to.  No excuses, just an explanation for this lame question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each() returns the original list, but that's not really for.  each() executes a function for each item in a list. For example, you could print something to the screen for each item, but you wouldn't want to do some transformation on each item because it doesn't give you the result of each function execution.

Instead, you can use map(). map() returns the result of calling a function for every item in a list, so you get the list of results and can then avoid getting the original list back.